# How to edit UITableView cell contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Just need to confirm one thing that i have searched enough on "How can i edit the contents of the Table" but the only findings are "Custom cells with text fields". Is this true that i only have a solution that for every cell i need a text field to edit its contents or is there any other good solution exist? If yes then let me know and if no just confirm the above finding

(Though question is not properly explained but hopefully you guys understand what i want to ask)

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default *UITableViewCell* won't support editing the text, because it uses *UILabel*'s to display the text. So, your finding, **"Custom cells with text fields"**, is the correct way to do it.